# Does joomla store article/ modules text and image path in database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, joomla, rss, joomla2.5

I wanted to create an iPhone app for a website which is created using Joomla 2.5. What I was thinking is to create RSS and pass that link in the iPhone app. However, for creating RSS, I was worried about from where should I get the articles text and images that are there?

Hence, I wanted to know: does Joomla store the article/ modules text and images path in a database? If yes, which table does it use to store all info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's stored in the database ;-)
You should find all the data in the table `#__content` (replace #__ with your prefix).
The fields `title`, `introtext`, `fulltext` and `images` is probably what you need. Note that the `images` field is an JSON encoded string.

Comment: When I see in my table I see text as `<p><img src="images/webdesigns.jpg" alt="" align="left" />` this is not useful.. ;) to get proper data for my app, I have to format the text...